# Magento 1 language packs

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, language, internationalization, language-package

This http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations says

> The community translation tool is offline as of August 27, 2014. We
>   will be providing a new and improved community-sourced translation
>   tool in the future. If you would like to assist with translating
>   Magento please send an email to community@magento.com.

What now? Does anyone have an idea where I can get the language packs I need?
For this particular case, I need a ro_RO language pack for CE-1.9. (yes, I know, I'm Romanian and I don't have a ro_RO language pack yet. I'm ashamed, but that's the situation).
And as a general question, where should people go get their language packs until the "new and improved community-sourced translation" is finished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Romania I've found this:
http://ext.topmage.com/extensions/20/32/Locale_Mage_community_ro_RO/

and:

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/magento-ce-1x/

But I'm not sure if it's still supported by project authors.

Where should we go: search GitHub repos, Google and go 20 pages.

It would be nice from Magento authors to at least make a GitHub repository with all language packs. I'm lucky I've copied those that I use.

Edit:
Based on archive that Marius have posted I've managed to make a public repository so you can download all language:
http://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales/

Comment: Thanks for the language pack. It's kind of old. It's for 1.0, but it's something. Better than starting from scratch. In the mean time I found one here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/ but still not the best. I will try to combine both of them. I guess my problem might be almost solved temporarily, but There is still a problem for most of the language packs.

Comment: I guess the rest can be taken from the same page I did, but this seams dirty. We should revolt.

Comment: Indeed, I'm starting to make a public GitHub repo, since we don't know how much time Magento Translations will be offline.

Comment: If some wouldn't have time to download every locale pack separately (webarchive is really slow...)

https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales

Comment: Nice...Just nice. please post the link in the answer and I will gladly accept the answer.

Comment: You may want to update your repo with a 99% complete translation for ro_RO. you can find it here: http://www.mindmagnetsoftware.com/blog/magento-romanian-translation/. The guys at Mind Magnet did a great job on this.

Answer (score 6):

Until we get a nice solution, we can use the snapshot of the language pack page from the magento forum from July 17th 2014: https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/

Answer (score 4):

Magento has announced an official crowdsourced translation tool.
See https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Translating-Magento/m-p/16945#U16945 for the announcement.

The tool is available here for Magento 1: https://crowdin.com/project/magento-1

Answer (score 1):

Question remains. Where to get language packages that fit to current Magento release?

I know you can find a lot localizations at *Magento Connect*, but most of them are not realy maintained. So, no.

---

> Magento has announced an official crowdsourced translation tool. See https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Translating-Magento/m-p/16945#U16945 for the announcement.
>
> The tool is available here for Magento 1: https://crowdin.com/project/magento-1
>
> **Tymoteusz Motylewski**

Announcement

> **Translating Magento**
>
> When I joined Magento over a year ago I took stock of where we were collaborating with the community to advance the Magento platform. One area in need of improvement was the translation tool. Magento installations serve merchants and their customers in dozens of languages, and for a long time we shipped Magento 1 with language packs for some of the popular languages. We also provided a tool for community-created translations, some of which were completed and delivered via Magento Connect. That said, there was no substantial process or curation involved in this tool, and it didn't facilitate interaction among each language's translators. Because the experience was substandard we removed access to this tool almost a year ago and began the search for a replacement.
>
> I'm delighted to report that we have found a replacement tool which will facilitate community-sourced translations, and we are now ready to accept contributions! The steps to become a translation contributor are below:
>
> - Register as a translator on crowdin.com.
> - Sign our CLA here http://magento.com/legaldocuments/mca. We cannot accept any contributions from people who do not sign this.
> - Visit our two separate projects at crowdin: Magento 1 and Magento 2
>
> Why are we going with a crowdsourced translation tool?
>
> - The power and expertise of our global ecosystem have already helped in the past
> - Our vast community exists in most markets, knows their markets and language best, and we rely on them (you) as experts
> - We want to enable translations even for the less popular languages, giving a chance for everyone to contribute in a very meaningful way to the Magento platform
>
> We are excited as always to incorporate the effort and knowledge of our community to help make Magento better for merchants and consumers!
>
> *Huge thanks to Piotr Kaminski for his efforts in getting this project ready to go.*
>
> <sup>@benmarks, Developer & Community Evangelist at Magento</sup>

I've toyed around with "crowdin" project and **it's really cool**.

Seems translation source is pretty old *(and doesn't fit 1.9.3.4)*, but still good staring point.

It just takes a few time to import existing translations *(tried with german/itailan)*.

---

### If there woulnd't only be `73 users participate in this project` ...

... and if *Magento* could remove `Enterprise` files *and add a versioning system (or at least offer latest translations)*, that could be a really good source for locale packages. :(

### https://crowdin.com/project/magento-1

<sup>https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2</sup>