# get list or collection of all translations in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I want to know what are the places to look for the translations in Magento.

What would be the best way to get a list or collection of all translations in Magento?

Where would one start in the creation of a translation module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for existing source, if so refer to this question and answer:

[Magento 1 language packs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40170/magento-1-language-packs/40175#40175)

If you would like to create translation for language that seems not be done yet (after searching transifex projects, github, webarchive etc.) I'd suggest to start with copying directory:

```
/magento/app/locale/en_US/
```

into

```
/magento/app/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGECODE
```

And then just translate each phrase that are on right side of original sentence, i.e. in files referred to english (code en_US) we would have:

```
"Checkout","Checkout"
```

and in file for polish language (code pl_PL) we would have:

```
"Checkout","Zamówienie"
```

**Remember to keep encoding of files to UTF-8 Without BOM.** To do that best way is use some editor like Notepad++ where you can easily choose your encoding. Try to avoid OpenOffice Calc and MS Office Excel as they can do some harm to your files if used in not the right way.

Comment: Good answer - I'd like to suggest to keep file encoding as utf-8 as there is really no need for anything else.

Comment: I was going to write it, but then I've stumbled upon two things...what about Russian locale? I don't think we have cyrylic in UTF-8. And second one...we should advice to save into **UTF-8 (Without BOM)** like default en_US is. I'm not sure what's the really difference in encoding Without Byte Ordered Mark encoding.

Comment: Cyrillic is not a problem - see everything that's covered here http://www.unicode.org/charts/, it might be that the font you are using does not have the characters but that is a display issue rather than encoding. In regards to BOM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8 so I would say leave it out unless you have a very good reason to use it.